# Rate Equations Appearing in Ecology - Confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

In ecology and fisheries science it is common to calculate the rates of growth, natural mortality, fishing mortality, immigration, emigration, etc. using 'instantaneous' rates. I understand instantaneous rates in the context of finance and banking better than in ecology. There is likely something basic I'm missing here but I'm stumped to figure this out.

To calculate the number of individuals alive at time t, I am given the following equation:
$$
N_{t+1} = N_{t}e^{-M_{0}-(C_{t}+Q_{t})/B_{t}}
$$
where N is the number of individuals, M<sub>0</sub> is 'base instantaneous natural mortality', C<sub>t</sub> is 'catch in year t', Q<sub>t</sub> is consumption in year t (by a specific natural predator), and B<sub>t</sub> is a proportion of total biomass (not numbers) vulnerable to predation and fishing.

I'm given little information about units. From what I understand, M<sub>0</sub> is a mortality rate that is instantaneous with year<sup>-1</sup> units. B<sub>t</sub> is actual biomass, not a rate. C<sub>t</sub> and Q<sub>t</sub> are likewise absolute biomass. Thus we are summing instantaneous mortality rate with a proportion. Why?

To be more specific about why I'm confused, M<sub>0</sub> to me is a number that is same as ln(m) where m is an annual (or time step t) proportion of the population that dies from natural mortality. Then, why would $(C_{t}+Q_{t})/B_{t}$ appear in the exponent? This is a proportion of total at a time-step t - it doesn't make sense to me why it would be treated as 'instantaneous'.

Comment: OK, it's something I will follow up on

Comment: @LutzLehmann , No, observed that the exponential factor is being multiplied by $N_t$, rather than $N_0$, so it only represents the rate of change over that *one* year.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I've made a correction to the formula since his response. Still confused though about the proportion in the exponential. Wouldn't it be better to put, say, ln((Ct+Qt)/Bt) in exponential?

Comment: Yes, this makes more sense now. But still, the question of the other terms remains. Is "catch" and "consumption" also relative to the total biomass? Then the quotient would make more sense, as in first order it would be approximately equal to $N_te^{-M_0}-(C_t+Q_t)\frac{N_t}{B_t}e^{-M_0}$, so that both are apportioned relative to the size of the species.

Comment: @LutzLehmann it's relative to total vulnerable Biomass, so not absolute total. And so the whole term is a proportion of a proportion. I found this note, and I think it is connected to why I can't understand the big idea here i.e. I never understood rate calculations this way. "Note that the f(x) at time t for equations of form f(x)’ = -ax are easily calculated exactly using e^-at " So, if the rate of loss (a) due to fishing and 'consumption' is 50% per year and f(x)' = 0.5x then the rate at any time is e^-0.5t... hmm